# why am I getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on assign?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var lineItemTracker = new Array();
lineItemsTracker[i]['sales_order_line_item_id'] = result[i].sales_order_line_item_id;
```

This throws the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined on assign
```

if I check

```
console.log(result[i].sales_order_line_item_id);
```

then I get the correct result.  When I check

```
console.log('here ' + lineItemsTracker[i]['sales_order_line_item_id']);
```

I get the error message.

```
lineItemsTracker[1]['sales_order_line_item_id'] = 'test';
```

Produces the error.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: You have a typo there lineItemTracker v/s lineItemsTracker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** As noted by others, you have a typo, but even After correcting the typo it will not work with the code you have written.

You are trying to access an invalid index and as a result you are getting the error. Use the `push` method of the Array to add the elements.

```
var lineItemTracker = new Array();
lineItemsTracker.push(result[i].sales_order_line_item_id);
```

**Explaination:**

**1.** When you create an array like `var lineItemTracker = new Array();`
`lineItemTracker` is created an an array but the length is `0`.

**2.** Next, when you write `lineItemsTracker[i]` it means you are trying to access the element at index `i`. Since, the length of the array is zero, It will return `undefined` as there is no element defined at that index.

**3.**  Next, `lineItemsTracker[i]['sales_order_line_item_id']` This lines try to access the property `sales_order_line_item_id` on an `undefined` object and then you will get the error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sales_order_line_item_id' of undefined on assign

Comment: its just a typo

Comment: Yeah good eye, But even after correcting the typo, it will not work because of the reason i explained.

Comment: You are completely right. Thank you. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. It should be `var lineItemsTracker = new Array();`

You don't have an s in the definition but you put an s everywhere you reference it

Comment: Good catch Hadas, but even after correcting the Typo, the code will not work as this is not the way array elements are added to an empty array.

Comment: True. The error message would be different though, it would be that you can't read property 'sales_order_line_item_id' of unassigned because now lineItemsTracker[0] will be the undefined object. Not that it really matters :p

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting Agalo's answer - if nothing else he got there first - but upvoted.